# How to make a regex that shows words that have only n,m characters

Tags: regex, grep

If I have the following contents in `file`:

```
watermelon
banana
apple
pineapple
apppppple
```

How do I construct the regex so that it only shows me words where there is a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 4 consecutive 'p' characters? I tried

```
egrep 'p{2,4}' file
```

but this includes apppppple, which I do not want.

```
[root@localhost ~]# egrep 'p{2,4}' file
apple
pineapple
apppppple
```

Comment: `grep -P '(?<!p)p{2,4}(?!p)' file` or `grep -E '([^p]|^)p{2,4}([^p]|$)' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
grep -E '([^p]|^)p{2,4}([^p]|$)' file # POSIX ERE regex flavor
grep -P '(?<!p)p{2,4}(?!p)' file      # PCRE regex flavor, GNU grep only
```

The `([^p]|^)` part matches any char other than `p` or start of string, and `([^p]|$)` matches any char other than `p` or end of string.

The `(?<!p)p{2,4}(?!p)` pattern matches two, three or four `p`s that are not preceded nor followed with `p`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/sIuKGc):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='watermelon
banana
apple
pineapple
apppppple'
grep -E '([^p]|^)p{2,4}([^p]|$)' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
apple
pineapple
```